# All variants of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, combinatorics

I have an array that is structured like this one:

```
  array = ["one","two","three","four"];
```

How can I get all possible variants of this array, in all possible lengths 1-4:

```
  ar = [["one"]["two"]["three"]["four"]["one","two"]
       ["one","three"] ["one","three","four"]]
```

I think in the end there should be 4*4*4*4 elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh i think i found an answer by myself,  i also could combine this arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.combination(1).to_a  #=> [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
a.combination(2).to_a  #=> [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
a.combination(3).to_a  #=> [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
a.combination(4).to_a  #=> [[1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 4):

> How can i get all possible variants of this array[...]

Use [`Array#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
array.combination(3).to_a
```

Result:

```
[["one", "two", "three"],
 ["one", "two", "four"],
 ["one", "three", "four"],
 ["two", "three", "four"]]
```

> [...]in all possible lengths 1-4

Use a range, iterate over it with [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
(1..array.length).flat_map {|len| array.combination(len).to_a }
```

Result:

```
[["one"],
 ["two"],
 ["three"],
 ["four"],
 ["one", "two"],
 ["one", "three"],
 ["one", "four"],
 ["two", "three"],
 ["two", "four"],
 ["three", "four"],
 ["one", "two", "three"],
 ["one", "two", "four"],
 ["one", "three", "four"],
 ["two", "three", "four"],
 ["one", "two", "three", "four"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the ***combinatoric powerset***.

The [combinatorics gem](https://github.com/postmodern/combinatorics) does this

```
["one","two","three","four"].powerset
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   def combinations(array)
      m = array.length
      (1...2**m).map do | n |
        (0...m).select { | i | n[i] == 1 }.map { | i | array[i] }
      end
    end
```

Tested and has the result:

```
irb(main):001:0> array = ["one","two", "three","four"];
irb(main):003:0> m = array.length
=> 4
irb(main):004:0> (1...2**m).map do |n|
irb(main):005:1* (0...m).select { |i| n[i] == 1}.map {|i| array[i]}
irb(main):006:1> end
=> [["one"], 
["two"], 
["one", "two"], 
["three"], 
["one", "three"], 
["two", "three"], 
["one", "two", "three"], 
["four"], 
["one", "four"], 
["two", "four"], 
["one", "two", "four"], 
["three", "four"], 
["one", "three", "four"], 
["two", "three","four"], 
["one", "two", "three", "four"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, the result should have 4**4 elements, you can do it like this:

```
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
  a = array.product(*[array]*(array.size-1))
  #=> [["one", "one", "one", "one"], ["one", "one", "one", "two"],
  #    ...
  #    ["four", "four", "four", "three"], ["four", "four", "four", "four"]]
a.size
  #=> 256
a.size == 4**4
  #=> true
```

but that is inconsistent with your example.  If you don't want to have elements repeat, but include, for example, both `["one", "two"]` and `["two", "one"]` in the result:

```
a = (1..array.size).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
      a.concat(array.permutation(i).to_a) }
  #=> [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"], 
  #    ["one", "two"], ["one", "three"], ["one", "four"], ["two", "one"],
  #    ["two", "three"], ["two", "four"], ["three", "one"], ["three", "two"],
  #    ["three", "four"], ["four", "one"], ["four", "two"], ["four", "three"],
  #    ["one", "two", "three"], ["one", "two", "four"],
  #    ...
  #
  #    ["four", "three", "one"], ["four", "three", "two"],
  #    ["one", "two", "three", "four"], ["one", "two", "four", "three"],
  #    ...
  #    ["four", "three", "one", "two"], ["four", "three", "two", "one"]]

a.size
  #=> 64
a.size == 4*3*2*1 + 4*3*2 + 4*3 + 4
  #=> true
```

Lastly, just replace `permuation` with `combination` if you want combinations of elements rather than permuatations of elements:

```
a = (1..array.size).each_with_object([]) { |i,a|
      a.concat(array.combination(i).to_a) }
  #=> [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"],
  #    ["one", "two"], ["one", "three"], ["one", "four"],
  #      ["two", "three"], ["two", "four"], ["three", "four"],
  #    ["one", "two", "three"], ["one", "two", "four"],
  #      ["one", "three", "four"], ["two", "three", "four"],
  #    ["one", "two", "three", "four"]]
a.size
  #=> 15
a.size == 4*3*2/(1*(3*2)) + 4*3*2/(2*2) + 4*3*2/((3*2)*1) + 4*3*2/(4*3*2)
  #=> true
a.size == 2**4 - 1
  #=> true
```